# Testcafe installation with npm needs python an VisualStudio

Tags: testing, npm, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm working with testcafe for a while now and never had this problem before.
I had to reinstall testcafe on a new machine wir node 16.16.0 and npm 8.11.0 and used `npm install -g testcafe`

First it told me I need to install python. That confused me because my old PC didn't have Python installed but I did install it.
Now it tells me to install VisualStudio??
[error needs VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fEM6.png)

What am I doing wrong or does Testcafe really need Visual Studio now?

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem about a month ago when I updated `gpu.js`. The problem is that one of your project's dependencies is trying to build addons using the deprecated `node-gyp`. I managed to find two ways to fix this: install an older version of node.js or override `node-gyp` in `package.json`. The `node-gyp` override in my case looked like this:

```json
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gpu.js": "^2.15.2",
    "node-gyp": "9.0.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "node-gyp": "9.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "node-gyp": "9.0.0"
  }
}
```